# How to update 2 target with htmx?

Tags: htmx

I have following htmx code

```
<button
        hx-get="/views/users/byId/someId"
        hx-target=".details">Details</button>
<div class="details">first</div>
<div class="details">second</div>
```

This only change first div and second div does not change
I want to update both div in the bottom with same class name
How to do this this?

I also tried multiple div but as we cant have multiple div that was giving error

Answer (score 7):

The documentation for [hx-target](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-target/) says that transactions like hx-get and hx-post will only replace the *first* DOM node on the page that matches the criteria.  This is true whether you're  using the default action (which swaps out the current DOM node) or specifying your own CSS selector.

This is a pretty common question for htmx, and there's an example of [several different ways to accomplish this](https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/) on the website.  This example lists three possible solutions:

1. Use [hx-target](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-target/) to swap a larger portion of the page.
2. Use [Out of Band Swaps](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/)
3. Use custom events and [hx-trigger](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/) to trigger additional swaps that follow after the initial one.

It's hard to say what's the "right" answer without looking at the rest of your use case.  But my guess is that you could just expand the area you're targeting and call it a day.

```html
<div id="swap-all-this">
    <button
        hx-get="/views/users/byId/someId"
        hx-target="#swap-all-this">Details</button>
    <div class="details">first</div>
    <div class="details">second</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note there is also the [`multiswap` extension](https://htmx.org/extensions/multi-swap/), which can target multiple elements.

Eg

```
<button
  hx-get="/views/users/byId/someId"
  hx-target=".details"
  hx-swap="multi:#id1,#id" <!--THIS IS NEW HERE-->
  >Details</button>
<div class="details" id="id1">first</div>
<div class="details" id="id2">second</div>
```

Note that you would have to include and enable the htmx extension according to the [documentation](https://htmx.org/extensions/multi-swap/).